# WordPress and CodeIgniter htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a site with **WordPress** e.g `http://example.com/` and **CodeIgniter** in subdirectory e.g `http://example.com/drinking-water-database/`

The CodeIgniter URL `http://example.com/drinking-water-database/developer` works fine.
I want to remove `drinking-water-database` from URL. Means `http://example.com/developer` will show the content of `http://example.com/drinking-water-database/developer`. I have write the htaccess but it's not working.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^developer
RewriteRule "^developer/(.*)/$" "drinking-water-database/index.php?/developer/$1" [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have tried every possible pattern. Even I tried only the redirect rule to make developer link working with bellow htaccess. But http://example.com/developer showing 404.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^developer/(.*)/$" "drinking-water-database/index.php?/developer/$1" [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Well `developer` obviously does not match the pattern `^developer/(.*)/$`, how is that actually surprising to you?

Comment: I have tried different kind of pattern. e.g: `RewriteRule developer "drinking-water-database/index.php?/developer/ [L]" drinking-water-database/index.php?/developer/`
or  `RewriteRule (.*) "drinking-water-database/index.php?/developer/" [L]`

Comment: Why are you trying to make an external redirect to begin with? If you want the URL in the browser address bar to _stay_ at `/developer/`, then this needs to be an internal rewrite.

Comment: Without the attempts at specifically rewriting this, does `http://example.com/drinking-water-database/index.php?/developer/` show the desired content in the first place?

Comment: I am trying to do an internal redirect. `http://example.com/drinking-water-database/index.php?/developer/` this URL is also a valid URL for CodeIgniter.

Comment: `http://example.com/drinking-water-database/index.php?/developer/` and `http://example.com/drinking-water-database/developer/` gives the same output in CodeIgniter.

Comment: I am sorry if I am doing it wrong. but does my htaccess code doing an external redirect?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Comment: I have tried without R flags. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63485285/wordpress-and-codeigniter-htaccess?noredirect=1#comment112261227_63485285

Comment: I am searching google with `internal .htaccess redirect` solutions. visited about 20-30 solution in StackOverflow and trying all possible patterns. But didn't succeed. Finally, I have posted the last solution I have tried.

Comment: why dont you just configure your [routes](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html?highlight=routes)?

Comment: The main .htaccess file for WordPress. So I have to prevent developer URI to go to WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with this:

Replace

```
RewriteRule "^developer/(.*)/$" "drinking-water-database/index.php?/developer/$1" [L,R=301]
```

with

```
RewriteRule (.*) "drinking-water-database/index.php?/$1" [L]
```